# Differentiating $\ln\,\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)$ wrt $v$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to differentiate

$$-\frac{v}{2}\ln(2) - \ln\,\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)$$

I did it and got

$$-\frac{\ln(2)}{2} - \frac{\Gamma'(\frac{v}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2})}$$

But the answers say it should be

$$-\frac{\ln(2)}{2} - \frac{\Gamma'(\frac{v}{2})}{2\Gamma(\frac{v}{2})}$$

How?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dv}\left(-\frac{v}{2}\ln 2 -\ln \Gamma \left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2 -\frac{1}{\Gamma(v/2)} \frac{d}{dv} \Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\ =$$

$$= -\frac{1}{2}\ln 2 -\frac{1}{\Gamma(v/2)}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \Gamma '\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\ $$

Comment: So I have to use chain rule to do $\frac{d}{dv} \left( \Gamma \left(\frac{v}{2} \right) \right)$?

Comment: Of course, @Kaish: how else? It is the composition of two functions.\

Answer (score 0):

Let's $f(u)=\frac{u}{2}$. Then, 
$$
-\frac{v}{2}\ln(2) - \ln\,\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)=
-\ln(2)\cdot f(u)-\ln\circ \Gamma\circ f(u)
$$
By chain rule, 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{du}\bigg[-\ln(2)\cdot f(u)-\ln\circ \Gamma\circ f(u)\bigg]=
&
-\ln(2)\cdot \frac{1}{2}
\\
-&
\bigg( D_z\ln(z)\bigg|_{z=\Gamma\circ f(u)} \bigg)
\cdot \bigg(D_y\Gamma(y)\bigg|_{y=f(u)} \bigg)\cdot \bigg( D_x f(x)\bigg|_{x=u} \bigg)
\end{align}